# HealthKit query for swimming strokes / style per lap

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos

I managed to query for swimming strokes but it's just the cumulative sum.

```
private func querySwimStrokeCount(for sample: HKSample) {
    let strokeCount = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.swimmingStrokeCount)!
    let sampleDate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: sample.startDate, end: sample.endDate, options: [])
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: strokeCount,
                                  quantitySamplePredicate: sampleDate,
                                  options: .cumulativeSum) { (query, statisticsOrNil, errorOrNil) in
        
        guard let statistics = statisticsOrNil else {
            return
        }
        
        let sum = statistics.sumQuantity()
        let strokeCount = sum?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()) ?? 0
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.strokeCount = Int(strokeCount)
        }
    }
    
    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

Now I came to the question how do I get the stroke count per lap and the swimming style for that lap? The Apple Health App shows this data (see screenshots) but I have no clue how to query for them.

Any help appreciated!

[image: Health App Swimming Strokes per lap]

[image: Health App Swimming Style for strokes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@incmiko's answer pointed me in the right direction by looking at `HKSampleQuery`. However his/her code did not help me. So here is what I did to get the stroke style per lap.

```
private func querySwimStrokes(for sample: HKSample) {
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .swimmingStrokeCount)!
    let sampleDate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: sample.startDate, end: sample.endDate, options: [])
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType,
                              predicate: sampleDate,
                              limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                              sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { query, samplesOrNil, errorOrNil in
        
        samplesOrNil?.forEach({ sample in
                            
            if let quantitySample = sample as? HKQuantitySample {
                let strokes = quantitySample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                print(strokes)
            }
            
            if let strokeStyleInt = sample.metadata?["HKSwimmingStrokeStyle"] as? Int,
               let strokeStyle = HKSwimmingStrokeStyle(rawValue: strokeStyleInt){
                print(strokeStyle)
            }
        })
    }
    
    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `HKStatisticsQuery` which is just for getting aggregated data.

> Statistics queries calculate common statistics over the set of
> matching samples. You can use statistical queries to calculate the
> minimum, maximum, or average value of a set of discrete quantities, or
> use them to calculate the sum for cumulative quantities.

To get the real samples `HKSampleQuery`

> You can use sample queries to search for any concrete subclasses of
> the HKSample class, including HKCategorySample, HKCorrelation,
> HKQuantitySample, and HKWorkout objects. The sample query returns
> sample objects that match the provided type and predicate. You can
> provide a sort order for the returned samples, or limit the number of
> samples returned. Other query classes can be used to perform more
> specialized searches and calculations. For more information, see
> HKQuery.

or `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` which I prefer to monitoring all the changes

> Anchored object queries provide an easy way to search for new data in
> the HealthKit store. An HKAnchoredObjectQuery returns an anchor value
> that corresponds to the last sample or deleted object received by that
> query. Subsequent queries can use this anchor to restrict their
> results to only newer saved or deleted objects. Anchored object
> queries are mostly immutable. You can assign the query’s updateHandler
> property after instantiating the object, but you must set all other
> properties when you instantiate the object. You can’t change them.

And here is some hopefully helpful code for your problem

```
var anchor = self.getAnchorFor() // My private method to get the latest anchor for a type of HKEntry
let sampleType = HKObjectType

self.anchoredQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (query, samplesOrNil, deletedObjectsOrNil, newAnchor, errorOrNil) in
    
    guard let addedObjects = samplesOrNil, let deletedObjects = deletedObjectsOrNil else {
        // Handle the error here.
        return;
    }
    
    anchor = newAnchor
    self.storeNewAnchor() // My private method to store the latest anchor for a type of HKEntry
    
    for obj in addedObjects {
        if let sampleObj = obj as? HKWorkout{ // HKWorkout is just an example for a typ
            let uuid = sampleObj.uuid.uuidString
            let source = sampleObj.sourceRevision.source.name
            let sourceBundleID = sampleObj.sourceRevision.source.bundleIdentifier
            
            print("object added: " + uuid)
            print("source: " + source + " bundleID: " + sourceBundleID)
        }
    }
    
    for obj in deletedObjects {
        let uuid = obj.uuid.uuidString
        
        print("object deleted: " + uuid)

    }
    
    print("Finished-")
}


// Optionally, add an update handler.
self.anchoredQuery!.updateHandler = { (query, samplesOrNil, deletedObjectsOrNil, newAnchor, errorOrNil) in
    
    guard let addedObjects = samplesOrNil, let deletedObjects = deletedObjectsOrNil else {
        // Handle the error here.
        

        return;
    }
    
    anchor = newAnchor
    self.storeNewAnchor() // My private method to store the latest anchor for a type of HKEntry
    
    for obj in addedObjects {
        if let sampleObj = obj as? HKWorkout{ // HKWorkout is just an example for a typ
            let uuid = sampleObj.uuid.uuidString
            let source = sampleObj.sourceRevision.source.name
            let sourceBundleID = sampleObj.sourceRevision.source.bundleIdentifier

            print("object added: " + uuid)
            print("source: " + source + " bundleID: " + sourceBundleID)

        }
    }
    
    for obj in deletedObjects {
        let uuid = obj.uuid.uuidString
        
        print("object deleted: " + uuid)

    }
    
    print("Update Finished-")
}

// Run the query.
self.healthStore.execute(self.anchoredQuery!)
```

Comment: Ok I get the idea but your code is not really helping. I think I need the HKSampleQuery but I still cannot find the strokeCount per lap

Comment: Thanks, I gave you the bounty for pointing me into the right direction. However you should maybe remove your code because it is not related to the question.